# missing required parameters (laravel 8.8.0)

Tags: php, laravel, web, model-view-controller, laravel-8

Help. My laravel showing error "Missing required parameters for [Route: TindakanTransaksi] [URI: TindakanTransaksi/{created_at}]. (View: C:\Git\aafia\resources\views\TransaksiTindakan.blade.php)" eventhough i think it shouldn't

1. Routes:

```
Route::get('/TindakanTransaksi/{created_at}', [TransactionController::class, 'tindakan'])->name('TindakanTransaksi');
```

2. View(Button->html):

```
<td style="text-align:center"><a href="{{ route('TindakanTransaksi', $data->created_at) }}"><button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></a></td>
```

3. Controller:

```
public function tindakan(Request $request, $created_at){
        //return $created_at;
        $data = array();
        $cek = Transaction::where('status', "mencari_dokter")
                ->where('created_at', $created_at)
                ->first();
        $daftarTransaksi = Transaction::where('status', "mencari_dokter")->get();
        $tindakan = Tindakan::select('deskripsi')->get();
        $userini = Auth::user();
        $data['daftarTransaksi'] = $daftarTransaksi;

        $data['norm'] = $cek->nomor_rm;
        $data['poli'] = $cek->poli;
        $data['tanggal'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toFormattedDateString();
        $data['tindakan'] = $tindakan;
        $data['nodaftar'] = $cek->id;
        $data['nama_pasien'] = $cek->nama_pasien;
        $data['nama_dokter'] = $userini->name;
        //$data['tindakan'] = array("mencari_dokter", "bayar" );

        return view('TransaksiTindakan', $data);
    }
```

I have tried to return the $created_at above, no error at all and showing what i want. But when i run full code on the controller above, it started showing error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you should pass the parameters to the `route` helper as an associative array `['created_at' => ...]` ... and make sure what ever `$data->created_at` is isn't null; as there is no way to tell what `$data` is supposed to be in your view from just the controller

Comment: @lagbox i've just tried, put this into my View ```{{ route('TindakanTransaksi', ['created_at' => $data->created_at]) }}``` still same issue

Answer (score 1):

Make your href like this hyung

data->created_at]) }}">

Comment: Did you mean by this? ```route('TindakanTransaksi', ['created_at' => $data->created_at])```